# String Manipulation (Compare two string and copy common string)

Tags: c

I have to take 3 strings, a 'haystack' string, a 'needle' string, and a buffer string. I have to search the haystack string for a sequence matching the needle string, and copy the found result (the entire substring) from the haystack string into the buffer (do not copy the needle string).

Then I have to return a 1 if the matching sequence in the haystack is found and a 0 if the needle is not found.

This is the driver code:

```
#include "myprog.h"
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int myStrStr(char haystack[], char needle[], char buffer[]);
int main(){

    char haystack[][20] = {"chocolate","vanilla","caramel","strawberry","banana","cherry"};
    char needle[][20] = {"choc","lla","am","strawberry","na","terrible"};
    char buffer[255];

    printf("\n\t=========Testing myStrStr with '%s' and substring '%s'===========\n\n", haystack[0], needle[0]);
    int result = myStrStr(haystack[0],needle[0],buffer);
    assert(result == 1 && strcmp(needle[0], buffer) == 0);
    printf("\n\t\t....Test Passed\n");

    printf("\n\t=========Testing myStrStr with '%s' and substring '%s'===========\n\n", haystack[1], needle[1]);
    result = myStrStr(haystack[1],needle[1],buffer);
    printf("needle: %s, buffer: %s\n", needle[1], buffer );
    assert(result == 1 && strcmp(needle[1], buffer) == 0);
    printf("\n\t\t....Test Passed\n");

    printf("\n\t=========Testing myStrStr with 'blueberry' and substring 'ueber'===========\n\n");
    result = myStrStr(haystack[2],needle[2],buffer);
    assert(result == 1 && strcmp(needle[2], buffer) == 0);
    printf("\n\t\t....Test Passed\n");

    printf("\n\t=========Testing myStrStr with 'strawberry' and substring 'strawberry'===========\n\n");
    result = myStrStr(haystack[3],needle[3],buffer);
    assert(result == 1 && strcmp(needle[3], buffer) == 0);
    printf("\n\t\t....Test Passed\n");

    printf("\n\t=========Testing myStrStr with 'banana' and substring 'na'===========\n\n");
    result = myStrStr(haystack[4],needle[4],buffer);
    assert(result == 1 && strcmp(needle[4], buffer) == 0);
    printf("\n\t\t....Test Passed\n");

    printf("\n\t=========Testing myStrStr with 'grapefruit' and substring 'terrible'===========\n\n");
    result = myStrStr(haystack[5],needle[5],buffer);
    assert(result == 0);
    printf("\n\t\t....Test Passed\n");
}
```

I have to write my code in .h file. Below is my .h file

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

int myStrStr(char  * haystack, char * needle, char * buffer)
{
char *hays,*nee;
hays=haystack;
nee=needle;
buffer[0]='\0';
char s=sizeof(buffer);
char *tempbuffer=(char *)malloc(s);
  if(*hays=='\0' || *nee=='\0' )
  {
  printf("Haystack and Needle Cannot be Compared because Empty string cannot be compared\n");
  return 0;
  }     
  for(;*hays!='\0' ;hays++)
  {
    while(*hays==*nee && *hays!='\0' && *nee!='\0' )
    {        
      *tempbuffer=*hays; 
      strcat(buffer,tempbuffer);
      hays++;
      nee++;
    }
    if(*nee!= '\0'&& *tempbuffer!= '\0')
    {
    nee=needle;
    *buffer=NULL;
    }    
  }
  printf("%s\n",buffer);
  if(*nee=='\0')
  {  return 1;  }
  return 0;
}
```

I am getting the following message when trying to execute:

```
Assertion failed: result == 1 && strcmp(needle[0], buffer) == 0, file driver.c, line 35
```

EDIT:

I have made following changes in my code:

1. changed `char *tempbuffer=(char *)malloc(s);` to `char tempbuffer[255];`
2. Removed `*buffer=NULL;`

Now program is getting partially executed. For the first string i.e. "chocolate" and "choc" it prints the common substring which is required.

```
c
h
o
choc

                ....Test Passed
```

Problem starts when it has to print common sub string from "vanilla" and "lla". It is still printing the common letter from both string but it also prints the last letter from the previous string

```
c
l
l
lla
needle: lla, buffer: lla

                ....Test Passed
```

As you can see it prints "c" which is last word of previous string "choc"

Same happens for the third strings i.e. "caramel" and "am" But here my Assertion is getting failed

```
a
a
a
aam
needle: am, buffer: aam
Assertion failed: result == 1 && strcmp(needle[2], buffer) == 0, file assignment1.c, line 36, function main
Abort
```

I can't understand why this assertion failed and also why the last letter of previous string is also getting copied to next string?

Comment: You forgot to tell us what errors you are getting.

Comment: You probably did not mean to use sizeof here: `sizeof(buffer)` because `buffer` is a pointer.  If it were a string being passed to you, you could use `strlen`.  But since it is uninitialized on input to your function, there's no way to tell what size it is unless the caller passes a size parameter to tell you.

Comment: @BenVoigt I have edited and added what errors I am getting

Answer (score 1):

Your code is full of no-no's and unusual things. I will list a few of them.

1. Header files (.h) MUST NOT allocate memory. No declarations of variables, no C code.
2. `assert()` is used for different purposes usually. In your code, depending on you intention, `if()` should be enough.
3. The entire driver code can be made shorter and more readable using a `for` loop, for parsing through all the values of the arrays.
4. `char s=sizeof(buffer);` is totally not welcome. The function receives a pointer to a `char`, not to an array. Therefore the result is always X, regardless of what you use in the driver (X is the size of the pointer, architecture and compiler dependent, not the size of the array).
5. In `myStrStr()` you mix a non-standard `for` with a `while` (difficult to read AND UNDERSTAND quickly). Since you do not know the number of iterations from the beginning, only `while()`'s suit best.
6. In `myStrStr()` `buffer[0]='\0';` is a source of problems if `buffer` happens to point to unallocated memory.
7. **"I have to write my code in .h file."** Who forces you to do that? That is VERY bad practice for many reasons.
8. In the main file, you do not include the `.h` file.
9. You should use indentation and blank lines, to make the code readable and understandable.
10. As a result of 4., `tempbuffer` is too short/small, and you have a buffer overflow whenever you write any character after the first.
11. `"because Empty string cannot be compared"` Really? Why?

---

Practical: try to fix as many problems as possible.

1. Replace 
   char *tempbuffer=(char *)malloc(s);
   with
   char tempbuffer[255];
   (that is the size of `buffer`)
2. The way I understand your code, `tempbuffer` can actually be a simple `char` - no string, no array, no dynamic allocation...
3. No need to do `strcat(buffer,tempbuffer);` for each character.
4. `*buffer=NULL;` overwrites the content of `buffer` in function `main()`.
5. Use a debugger and go step-by-step to fine-tune things.

---

**EDIT**

This line:

```
  strcat(buffer,tempbuffer);
```

is a source of serious problems, because the content of `tempbuffer` might be random. You do not know if you have ANY '\0' inside, so the `strcat()` may concatenate all your RAM - until it hits a '\0'. One solution is to initialize all values of `tempbuffer` to '\0', at the beginning of the function.

Comment: I cannot make changes in driver code, since it is an assignment and driver code is given to us. I have to write my code in .h file, that is the instruction given to me. As for your point number 4, can you please tell what should I use instead of that. I have included my .h file in main file, I have not written that in my post, I will edit that.

Comment: The driver code MUST send the size of the buffer, as an additional parameter. Otherwise you cannot do anything to make sure that you will not generate a buffer overflow. If what you say is true, the person that teaches you C has very bad knowledge of programming.

Comment: I cant argue with my teacher on his teaching technique. Can you give me some tips on how can I make my program work

Comment: "Therefore the result is always 1"... no, it is the size in bytes of a pointer, which is architecture dependent and very rarely 1.  The important thing is that it doesn't tell you anything about the size of the buffer which the pointer addresses.

Comment: @pratteekshaurya: I agree with all 5 of the recommendations of this answer.

Comment: @virolino I have made few changes. I have edited my question and wrote what I am getting. Please see it

Comment: @BenVoigt: you are right about the size, I made a change.